# including timestamp in file name

Tags: unix, shell

I tried to create a file like this to put a timestamp in the file name

```
vim Customer1-$(date).txt
```

The result was `Customer1-Sat.txt`, however, I wanted the full timestamp

`Sat 30 Aug 2014 09:41:27 PDT`

I'm assuming the spaces in the output of the `Date` command were the reason why only `Sat` got included in the file name.

How to include the full timestamp?

Comment: Did you try wrapping the filename in quotes: `vim "Customer1-$(date).txt"`

Comment: @CryHavok thanks, that works, I'll accept your answer if you write a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely had files like Aug 2014 and 09:41:27 resulting.

Try this

```
timestamp=$(date +"%a %d %b %Y %k:%M:%S %Z").txt
touch customer1-"$timestamp".txt
```

Output:

```
customer1-Sun 31 Aug 2014  2:56:18 PDT.txt
```

I would not recommend this, as such file name would not be good for all configurations or on other operating systems.

Comment: ok, thanks, what format woudl you recommend for compatibility for other OSs

Comment: Basically avoid the ":", the spaces too can give you some headache when navigating, moving around or processing in scripts.
So if you replace them with hyphens or underscores, you should see no problems.
For example
`timestamp=$(date +"%a-%d-%b-%Y-%k-%M-%S-%Z").txt` would give you a file name like this `customer1-Sun-31-Aug-2014-11-16-38-PDT.txt`.